# Inject constructor with multiple same typed parameters

Tags: c#, autofac

I use autofac as DI container.
I'm aiming to inject the parameter `store` into the constructor.
That's what my constructor looks like.

```
public SomeClass (IMyCouchStore store)
{
    this.store = store;
}
```

The `store` parameter needs **two string parameters** in order to be instantiated:

```
// sample instantiation
var store = new MyCouchStore("http://someUri","someDbName");
```

I tried to register the two parameters during bootstrapping:

```
builder
    .RegisterType<MyCouchStore>()
    .As<IMyCouchStore>()
    .WithParameters(new [] {
        new NamedParameter("dbUri","http://someUri"),
        new NamedParameter("dbName","someDbName")
    }
```

However, I receive the following error:

***Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException***

*Cannot choose between multiple constructors with equal length 2 on type 'MyCouch.MyCouchStore'. Select the constructor explicitly, with the UsingConstructor() configuration method, when the component is registered.*

How can I inject multiple same typed parameters?

Comment: The error states: Select the constructor explicitly by `UsingConstructor() `

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your answer is in your question :)

> Select the constructor explicitly, with the `UsingConstructor()` configuration method.

---

```
public MyCouchStore(string httpSomeuri, string somedbname)
{
    this.SomeUri = httpSomeuri;
    this.SomeDbName = somedbname;
}
```

---

```
builder.RegisterType<MyCouchStore>()
    .As<IMyCouchStore>()
    .UsingConstructor(typeof (string), typeof (string))
    .WithParameters(new[] 
    {
        new NamedParameter("httpSomeuri", "http://someUri"),
        new NamedParameter("somedbname",  Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
    });
```

Comment: I searched the autofac documentation but wasn't able to find any example who features my use case. Could you provide an example?

Comment: That should sort it ;)